# Using SUM from one query in another query MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have two queries that I am trying to use together.

Query 1 produces a table of data from a payroll table. In the payroll table there could be multiple entries for a single person on the same day. So if the 'hours_type' is the same I want the hours added together before this query produces it's results.

```
SELECT   `payroll`.*, `personnel`.`assigned_shift`
FROM     `payroll`, `personnel` 
WHERE    `payroll`.`full_name`= `personnel`.`full_name` 
     AND `payroll`.`date` = '$f_date' 
     AND `personnel`.`assigned_shift` IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
ORDER BY `personnel`.`assigned_shift` ASC;
```

Query 2 will add `hours` together for duplicate entries that have `full_name` and `hours_type` the same. The results from this query are what I want query #1 to use for duplicate entries.

```
SELECT   *, SUM(`hours`) AS `hours` 
FROM     `payroll` 
GROUP BY `full_name`, `hours_type`
```

I have tried Union, Union All (learned neither of those work as the # of columns are different for some reason.) I don't quite understand how subqueries work though I have tried multiple attempts at a subquery. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I'm new to SQL).

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your two queries can be joined together as follows :

```
SELECT
    pe.full_name,
    pa.hours_type,
    SUM(hours) hours
FROM 
    personel pe
    LEFT JOIN payroll pa ON pa.full_name = pe.full_name AND pa.date = '$f_date'
WHERE
    pe.assigned_shift IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
GROUP BY 
    pe.full_name,
    pa.hours_type
ORDER BY p.assigned_shift
```

The query joins the records of the `personel` table with the `payroll` table, and aggregates the results by personel full name and hours type, along with the total hours.

For personel without payroll on that day, a record with empty `hours_type` and `hours` columns will be displayed. To not display these records, you can switch the `LEFT JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`.

You can adapt the list of non-aggragated fields (`pe.full_name`, '`pa.hours_type`) as you wish ; every non-aggregated field must also appear in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Remarks on your sql code :

- always use explicit joins instead of implicit joins
- avoid using backticks unless really necessary : they make the query harder to read
- use table aliases to shorten the query
- avoid `SELECT *` : be specific about the columns that you want to select
- in non-ancient versions on MySQL, all non-aggregated columns must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause (note that this does not play well with `SELECT *`).

Comment: Thank you! That is what I just figured out how to do prior to your reply. I am using a join. As for the back ticks Maria DB wouldnt recognize what I am doing w/o them. Maybe I am doing that wrong too?

Comment: Welcome @AWilkinson ! Ah yes backticks may be required in MariaDB, I guess that will fall in the `unless really necessary` category...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to GMB for responding.

Just prior to his response I was able to get it working as a join. Here is my working query for anyone who may have a similar issue.

```
SELECT `payroll`.*, `personnel`.`assigned_shift`, SUM(`hours`) AS `hours`
FROM `payroll`
INNER JOIN `personnel` ON `payroll`.`full_name` = `personnel`.`full_name`
WHERE `date` = '$f_date' AND `personnel`.`assigned_shift` IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
GROUP BY `full_name`, `hours_type`
ORDER BY `personnel`.`assigned_shift`, `personnel`.`l_name`
```

Sorry about the back tics MariaDB seems to require them.